# FastAPI and SQLAlchemy - How to build relationships so "User" can be deleted with all their owned items?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, fastapi

I think I have a simple problem but I cannot understand where exactly I am making a mistake. My architecture look like that:

```
class CreditsTransaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'credits_transaction'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    credit_amount = Column(Integer)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

    # user = relationship('User', backref=backref("CreditsTransaction", cascade="all,delete"))
    

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    credit_balance = Column(Integer)
    username = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())

    # credits_transaction = relationship("CreditsTransaction", cascade="all,delete", backref="user")
```

In this code there are two commented lines, I tried all combinations, I think (according to tutorials) it should work with only second one uncommented. But with that I am getting error - `ERROR:  relation "user" does not exist at character 13`. Googling that didn't help me much. I am sure that table user is created properly because above I can see `Detected added table 'user'`.

I tried changing the code in various ways but I cannot get it to work. (if I leave them commented, the api is working properly except deleting users that have some CreditsTransaction objects).

Here is the error when I try to delete this user - `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) update or delete on table "user" violates foreign key constraint "credits_transaction_user_id_fkey" on table "credits_transaction"` and `DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) is still referenced from table "credits_transaction".`.

I know that I am looking for some SQLAlchemy version of Django's `on_delete` but I cannot implement it properly. Could someone please help me?

||||| EDIT: |||||

I think I got that with this code from SQLAlechemy docs:

```
class CreditsTransaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'credits_transaction'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    credit_amount = Column(Integer)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))

    user = relationship('User', back_populates="credits_transaction")

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    credit_balance = Column(Integer)
    username = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())

    credits_transaction = relationship("CreditsTransaction", back_populates="user", cascade="all,delete", passive_deletes=True)
```

But this one also results in this error - `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) update or delete on table "user" violates foreign key constraint "credits_transaction_user_id_fkey" on table "credits_transaction"`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/Uddyh9ph) works fine for me.

Comment: Also, verify that the `credits_transaction` table in the database actually has a foreign key declared with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. If you simply modify a model after the table is created then the table structure is *not* automatically updated.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you! I compared my code with yours and I found my problem. Your example is working great. Thanks!